# Vanilla TeXlive and wxMaxima on Ubuntu

Tags: texlive

In order to install vanilla texlive (thanks for the excellent tutorial), I removed everything tex from Ubuntu, including wxmaxima. Now, when I want to install wxmaxima again, it also wants to install tex-common. Would that break my beautiful new texlive installation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you finalise the TeXLive installation according to these [instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/39222)?
If you don't provide a "fake" TeX Debian package, it is likely to break your TeXLive setup.
Credits to user "cfr"!

Comment: I did, but I don't think that the texlive-local file that went into making the fake package mentions tex-common. Perhaps this is why wxmaxima wants to install it. The question is, what happens if I agree?

Comment: The suggested "content" of the fake package are tailored to Debian. If Ubuntu requires "tex-common" then simply add this (and any others that Ubuntu requires) to the list and redo the package. Then you should be safe installing wxmaxima via the Ubuntu package manager. You will run into troubles if you let Ubuntu install its own LaTex-package.

Comment: Hm, just checked with Synaptic (I am on Kubuntu 14.04), it seems to require only "tex-common". so if you add this to the contents list, you should be able to install wxmaxima without any further problems.